# Open a xml from url (python)

Tags: python, xml, parsing, urllib

I am trying to parse an xml from an url.

So originaly my code looked like this:

```
from xml.dom import minidom                                          
xmldoc = minidom.parse('all.xml')
```

In this case the xml what I intend to parse was on my local harddrive and it worked out perfectly!

The next step was to parse a xml from an url.
A sensormeter from allnet constantly inserts xml data into the networkt which is over the following url with a browser accessible: 192.168.60.242/xml

this is the xml:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
</head>
<body>
<form>
<textarea rows="50" cols="132"><xml><data> <devicename>ALL4000</devicename> <n0>0</n0><t0> 2.39</t0><min0> 0.00</min0><max0> 2.55</max0><l0>-55</l0><h0>150</h0><s0>102</s0> <n1>1</n1><t1> 2.53</t1><min1> 2.32</min1><max1> 10487.04</max1><l1>-55</l1><h1>150</h1><s1>102</s1> <n2>2</n2><t2> 2.55</t2><min2> 0.00</min2><max2> 2.55</max2><l2>-55</l2><h2>150</h2><s2>102</s2> <n3>3</n3><t3>-20480.00</t3><min3> 0.00</min3><max3> 5580.80</max3><l3>-55</l3><h3>150</h3><s3>0</s3> <n4>4</n4><t4>-20480.00</t4><min4> 40.96</min4><max4> 41943.04</max4><l4>-55</l4><h4>150</h4><s4>0</s4> <n5>5</n5><t5>-20480.00</t5><min5> 10.24</min5><max5> 0.08</max5><l5>-55</l5><h5>150</h5><s5>0</s5> <n6>6</n6><t6>-20480.00</t6><min6> 0.00</min6><max6>-20480.00</max6><l6>-55</l6><h6>150</h6><s6>0</s6> <n7>7</n7><t7>-20480.00</t7><min7> 0.00</min7><max7> 0.00</max7><l7>-55</l7><h7>150</h7><s7>0</s7> <n8>8</n8><t8>-20480.00</t8><min8> 336855.04</min8><max8> 1342177.28</max8><l8>-55</l8><h8>150</h8><s8>0</s8> <n9>9</n9><t9>-20480.00</t9><min9> 0.00</min9><max9> 0.00</max9><l9>-55</l9><h9>150</h9><s9>0</s9> <n10>10</n10><t10>-20480.00</t10><min10> 0.00</min10><max10> 0.00</max10><l10>-55</l10><h10>150</h10><s10>0</s10> <n11>11</n11><t11>-20480.00</t11><min11> 0.00</min11><max11> 0.00</max11><l11>-55</l11><h11>150</h11><s11>0</s11> <n12>12</n12><t12>-20480.00</t12><min12> 0.00</min12><max12> 0.00</max12><l12>-55</l12><h12>150</h12><s12>0</s12> <n13>13</n13><t13>-20480.00</t13><min13> 0.00</min13><max13> 0.00</max13><l13>-55</l13><h13>150</h13><s13>0</s13> <n14>14</n14><t14>-20480.00</t14><min14> 0.00</min14><max14> 0.00</max14><l14>-55</l14><h14>150</h14><s14>0</s14> <n15>15</n15><t15>-20480.00</t15><min15> 0.00</min15><max15> 0.00</max15><l15>-55</l15><h15>150</h15><s15>0</s15> <fn0>1</fn0><ft0>0</ft0><fs0>0</fs0> <fn1>2</fn1><ft1>0</ft1><fs1>0</fs1> <fn2>3</fn2><ft2>0</ft2><fs2>0</fs2> <fn3>4</fn3><ft3>0</ft3><fs3>0</fs3> <fn4>5</fn4><ft4>0</ft4><fs4>0</fs4> <fn5>6</fn5><ft5>0</ft5><fs5>0</fs5> <fn6>7</fn6><ft6>0</ft6><fs6>0</fs6> <fn7>8</fn7><ft7>0</ft7><fs7>0</fs7> <fn8>9</fn8><ft8>0</ft8><fs8>0</fs8> <fn9>10</fn9><ft9>0</ft9><fs9>0</fs9> <fn10>11</fn10><ft10>0</ft10><fs10>0</fs10> <fn11>12</fn11><ft11>0</ft11><fs11>0</fs11> <fn12>13</fn12><ft12>0</ft12><fs12>0</fs12> <fn13>14</fn13><ft13>0</ft13><fs13>0</fs13> <fn14>15</fn14><ft14>0</ft14><fs14>0</fs14> <fn15>16</fn15><ft15>0</ft15><fs15>0</fs15> <rn0>0</rn0><rt0>0</rt0> <rn1>1</rn1><rt1>0</rt1> <rn2>2</rn2><rt2>0</rt2> <rn3>3</rn3><rt3>0</rt3> <it0>248</it0><it1>255</it1><it2>255</it2><it3>255</it3><it4>128</it4><it5>1</it5><it6>255</it6><it7>255</it7> <date>05.08.2006</date><time>07:54:10</time><ad>1</ad><ntpsync>-1</ntpsync><i>10</i><f>0</f> <sys>18773719</sys><mem>24760</mem><fw>2.89</fw><dev>ALL4000</dev> <sensorx>5</sensorx><sensory>3</sensory> </data></xml> </textarea>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

So I changed the code into this:

```
   import urllib
   from xml.dom import minidom
   xmldoc = minidom.parse(urllib.urlopen('https//192.168.60.242  /xml')).read()
```

Unfortunatelly it does not work.
If executed, This is what gets returned:

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py" line 86, in urlopen return
> opener.open(url)
>
> IOError: Errno socket error Errno 111 Connection refused

I hope someone can help me out on this.

thanks

Comment: Does the website require you to login?

Comment: it would be better to post the code rather than a picture of it. looking at the image, it looks like you dont have access to the url

Comment: When using the browser are you using HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: Please don't post images (or image links) of code and/or error messages. Paste the actual text of your code and the traceback into your your question, in code blocks to preserve the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try pinging your website from your code and make sure you don't have login privileges, log in to your admin cp and make sure your xml page allows users to read or change its permissions.

Alternatively, try this-

```
xmlUrl= urllib2.urlopen("http://192.168.60.242/xml" )
xmlUrl_string= xmlUrl.read()
parser.parseString( xmlUrl_string)
```